# Why do I get two different representation for 383 in base 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Based on the Basis representation Theorem, I should get a unique representation for 383. Right? But unfortunately, I am getting
$$383=4^4+2\times 4^3+0 \times 4^2+0\times 4^1+3 \times 4^0$$

$$383=4^4+1\times 4^3+3 \times 4^2+3\times 4^1+3 \times 4^0$$

Why basis Representation theorem is not working here?

Comment: The first one adds up to 387.

Comment: What's not working here is whatever method you used to get the first supposed representation. Most likely you made an arithmetic error or misapplied the method. You could show the method step by step if you want someone to try to spot the error.

Comment: $383-3$ is not divisible by $4^2.$

Comment: Since you haven’t given us *how* you got these answers, we really can’t say *why* you got wrong answers, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $12003_4 = 387_{10}$, so a mistaken calculation led to this. $11333_4$ is what you want.